# How to send a zpl-file directly to usb printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a **ZEBRA ZT230 300dpi ZPL printer** to which I m trying to send **direct commands (without driver)**. I have the following simple **zpl** file:

```
^XA
^LH30,30
^FO20,10^AD^FDHello World^F5
^XZ
```

I have tried the commands:

```
cat label.zpl > /dev/bus/usb/001/004

cat label.zpl > /dev/usb/lp0
```

But in both cases I get bash: **Permission denied**

How can I **send my file directly to the printer**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the user you do this with to be part of the GROUP `/dev/usb/lp0` is set to.

```
ls -l /dev/usb/lp0
```

to get owner and group for `/dev/usb/lp0`. The group is likely to be `lp`. If your user is `paul` that would be

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp paul
```

You need to restart the session to make this active.

Comment: Thanks it worked! One more question. Suppose I have a program that does this command. Is the "add to GROUP" change permanent?

Comment: Yes, until you remove the group from the user